# Digital whiteboard software?

Tags: gratis, productivity, information-management, todo, whiteboard

I'm having issues keeping things organized.  I have notebooks, calendar reminders, etc, but none of them do me any good, because if I am not looking at them, I kind of forget about them.

What I need is a digital type whiteboard software that I can dedicate a monitor to and have all my tasks listed on there, maybe a couple columns for like "urgent", "to do", "doing", and "done", something of that nature.

I want it to look similar to something like the picture below, where I can kind of write a quick note when I get a phone call or an email, move it around to where it needs to go, etc.

[image]

Windows 10.

Would prefer free, but will pay a small fee if need be.

Answer (score 3):

That is not just a "Whiteboard", that is called a [Kanban board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board).

And there are some online applications:

- The first option is [**Trello**](https://trello.com/). It has a free account and can be a collaborative board. The main advantage of it is that the interface is very clean and user-friendly.

  The advantage is that you can make an infinite amount of boards. The paid version allows you to store assets inside your account, but you can skip that.
- Another interesting one is [**Freedcamp**](https://freedcamp.com/), also focused on a collaborative board, and more or less the same free option.
- An open source project is [**Tuleap**](https://www.tuleap.org/).

But I must say the one you posted looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

After some time searching the interwebs myself, I actually found something that hit all the issues I need.

Web based wasn't one of my needs, but it doesn't really matter if it was web based or software based.  It gives me the ability to make my own columns, specifically the 4 I stated.  It gives me the ability to post notes on the board and move them around as needed.  It's also set up exactly how the picture is set up that I posted with the question, and best yet, it was free.  It is 100% what I was looking for.

[Realtime Board](https://realtimeboard.com)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try my [Portable Kanban](http://dmitryivanov.net):

- It works offline it's free, can be used commercially.
- It works on Windows only.
- It has a Pomodoro timer that is configurable (work/short pause/long
  pause intervals, sound)
- It has a lot of options for configuring UI and board (including fullscreen mode).
- May be used for teams too (requires Redis server).

Here's a screenshot of the board:

[image]

Disclosure: I'm developer of PK.

Comment: Incorrect link. Is there a new link?

Comment: Note: Development stopped in early 2018, the website closed around 7/2018 – so sadly this software is no longer available. @Dmitry if you're still around and have an updated link, please provide it.

Answer (score 2):

Glad, you've found a solution! If you ever decide that you need more, i would recommend checking out [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com).

It is exactly what you were looking for an electronic whiteboard to capture all of the moving parts of your project. You can use it with a team or alone and make it as simple or as intricate as needed. The nice thing is that it allows to use many additional features (such as notifications, integrations, predesigned agile boards, time tracking and others), but if you do not need them, they will not be present and intervene your workday.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something structured with a fixed set of columns and webbased is ok for you, I can recommend [zenkit](https://zenkit.com) that  also lets you organise your tasks / notes / objects in other useful views like boards, tables, mindmaps.

If you would like something more free-form, that lets you organize your notes on something like an infinite zoomable pinpoard, and you prefer a classic offline tool, you could give the [iMapping Tool](http://www.imapping.info) a try. Despite the german website, the tool itself is available in english. (Disclaimer: I am involved in the development of that tool).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [Ziteboard, a digital, web whiteboard](https://ziteboard.com), especially its [Sticky Notes](https://ziteboard.com/online-whiteboard-features/#sticky-notes) feature. You can add, remove, edit, change color, replace, resize post-its on the infinite canvas. Once you are done, you can publish the whiteboard that you can view with its unique link. You can switch back from the view mode to edit mode at any time. Unlike your photo in the opening question, Ziteboard uses vector graphics, so you can zoom in to read small font if needed.

Disclosure: I'm interested in Ziteboard.

Comment: Please mention your affiliation to the product.

Comment: Looks to me that you are more than "interested in Ziteboard"  also seen your user profile.